# Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a function or any way I could print the username of the user taking the print out of a report in CR 8.5??

This could be the windows user name or user name pertaining to a system like IFS where the reports are being generated from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you can pass in System.Environment.Username as a parameter to your report.

EDIT: (Thanks rexem)
If you were using CR V10 and BusinessObjects Enterprise you could look into using CurrentCEUserID in a formula field.

Comment: CurrentCEUserID was introduced in CR v10